# editable UITextArea values in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I need a basic UITableView with key and value. I modify each cell to contain a UILabel, and a UITextArea. My problem is when I click the cell, the cell gives the blue click-response, but the keyboard does not appear, and the UITextField is not showing any response for editing.

In - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath I can get the textField, and set text to it, but I want to open the keyboard for writing in the textField.

When I modify the cell, I set all UITextFields to firstResponder, without luck.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can use the UITableViewStyleValue1 and just set the detailTextlabel to be an UITextlabel in your CellForRow. But take care that the TextLabel has a fitting width and height. Then you dont have to select the Cell but can directly tap the UITextLabel

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any references for that?

Answer (score 0):

I looked up one of my older projects and found out I handled things a little different back then. Here is what I did:

```
cell = [self.aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPlaceCell];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:kPlaceCell] autorelease];
                }


//PlaceField = An Instance of UITextfield, which I implemented as classvar.             
               [self.placeField removeFromSuperview];

// setting frame and font for your textfield. If you have static text in your Textlabel you should have an higher x so maybe CGRectMake (1, 100, 218, 39)

                self.placeField.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 318, 39);
                self.placeField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];

//Adding your UITextfield to the UITableViewCell contentView

                [cell.contentView addSubview: self.placeField];
            }
```

If anyone wonders: I used this tableView so that the user can create an user account and used Placeholders for (Name, Date of birth,....) so I didn't need static text. ^^

Tell me how this works for you or if you need further explanations

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good idea. I ended up using EditingTableViewCell from Apples CoreDataRecipes example project, så I have not tested your code. I will keep this in mind, and test it next time!

Comment: Yeah its always the best idea to use sample code and guides from Apple and if it works for you that should be just fine :-)